# A python script in Docker needs to accessAPI data present in different Docker image

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

I am new to docker and trying to figure out the following:

I need to access API data by running docker image `docker run -dit -p 5000:5000 abc/xyz:v1.0.0`

I have created a python application which can access this data.
I have created docker file for python application too. I am trying to run the API docker image when building the python app docker. (I am sure that's not the right way). Please tell me how to approach this situation.

I want `docker run -i my-python-app` to somehow access `docker run -dit -p 5000:5000 abc/xyz:v1.0.0`

This is how my Docker file looks like:

````
COPY variants     /usr/local/variants
COPY requirements /usr/local/requirements
COPY tests        /usr/local/tests

RUN apk add -U python3 g++ docker \
    && python3 -m ensurepip \
    && rm -r /usr/lib/python*/ensurepip \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install --upgrade setuptools \
    && pip3 install -r /usr/local/requirements/common.txt

ENTRYPOINT docker run --privileged -dit -p 5000:5000 abc/xyz:v1.0.0

ENTRYPOINT ["python3",  "-m",  "usr.local.variants.main"]```
````

Answer (score 0):

With your `-p 5000:5000` option you can communicate your docker with your host, but if you want to communicate two docker in the same host, you need to define a docker network for them.

The easiest way to do that is launching dockers with `--net=host` options. This network allows your docker to use host interfaces, including localhost.

**EDIT: Adding more info**

1. Create docker image (I recommend without ENTRYPOINT lines, copying your binary to a directory that belongs to the path.
2. Just add net=host to your docker run command, just before creating image with docker build: `docker run -dit --net=host -p 5000:5000 abc/xyz:v1.0.0 python3 <your_entry_point_path>`
3. Add `--net=host` to other dockers that you launch.

Comment: could you please elaborate your answer?. or give run commands for both docker?

Comment: Edited, but I don't know the other docker launch command. You've posted only one of them. Furthermore, I don't understand why you define ENTRYPOINT twice in your dockerfile